# How can I change the color to the arrows navigation of the ngb-datapicker?

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, ngb-datepicker

I am using this [datapicker](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples) (the range selection) on a project and the blue color of the arrows in the navigation bar is not the right one and I want to change it. I searched on google and here and I can not found an answer that solve my problem.

I have this HTML:

```
<div id="calenderDisplay">
  <ngb-datepicker #dp (select)="onDateSelection($event)" [displayMonths]="2" [dayTemplate]="t" outsideDays="collapsed"></ngb-datepicker>

  <ng-template #t let-date let-focused="focused">
    <span class="bnt-link" style="color: #12A19A !important;"></span>
    <span class="custom-day"
         [class.focused]="focused"
         [class.range]="isRange(date)"
         [class.faded]="isHovered(date) || isInside(date)"
         (mouseenter)="hoveredDate = date"
         (mouseleave)="hoveredDate = null">
            {{ date.day }}
    </span>
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

And I try all of this CSS:

```
.bnt-link {
    color: #12A19A !important;
}

::ng-deep ul {
    background-color: #12A19A !important;
}

ngb-datepicker {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;

    .ngb-dp-header {
        background-color: rgba(52,104,191,1);
    }

    select {
        background-color: rgba(52,104,191,1);
        color: white;
    }
}

::ng-deep .ngb-dp-arrow-btn {
    background-color: black;
}
```

And I can not figure out how to change the color of the blue arrows in the [datapicker](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples)

Comment: Try to inspect the element and find the id of the arrow, so you can change on css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to utilize the ::ng-deep pseudo class selector to target the children of the component.  A description of this process is described here: 
https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/
Please note that ::ng-deep is going to soon be depricated and removed. My understanding is that there is not replacement solution yet in place, so for the time being, we need to continue using it.

EDIT: This code worked on my project, I placed it on the component CSS for the component where I called the ngb-datepicker:

```
::ng-deep div.ngb-dp-arrow > button {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: I tried the code that you write, but it's not working for me

Comment: Can you please explain further so that I can try to help you?

Comment: I've edited my answer to reflect the actual code that worked for changing the chevron arrow buttons.

Comment: Perfect, now it's working. I put this code in the general css and not work, but when I put it in the css of the component, then work!! Thank you so much!!